# Vue class binding, better syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this component with some dynamic classes but it looks a little messy and I can't seem to figure out if there's a better way to write it. The class binding in vue kind of confuses me.

I'm using pug btw, but the focus should be on the `:class` anyway

```
section.section(:class="{'section--margin-top': cartStep === 1 && cart.length >= 3, 'section--full-screen section--centered' : cartStep !== 1 || cart.length < 3 }")
```

Should I be using a computed property? Or maybe the array syntax (which I can't quite wrap my head around)? Or...?

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solutions it's to create a computed property where you list your classes and the condition to activate it, if the condition you write for one determinate class it **true** vuejs add this class to your element:

```
computed: {
  myClassName() {
    'section--margin-top': this.cartStep === 1 && this.cart.length >= 3,
    'section--full-screen section--centered': this.cartStep !== 1 || this.cart.length < 3
  } 

}
```

then in your pug code:

```
section.section(:class="myClassName")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of computed properties and using template literal syntax would clean it up:

```
:class="`section--margin-top: ${marginTop}, section--full-screen section--centered: ${fullScreenCentered}`"

computed: {
    marginTop () {
        return this.cartStep === 1 && this.cart.length >= 3
    },
    fullScreenCentered () {
        return this.cartStep !== 1 || this.cart.length < 3
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with pug so hope this translates properly.

Comment: Yes this would definitely work on pug and it is for sure a little cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So there are 4 approaches to consider:

1. Object Syntax - `{ 'a': true, 'b': false, 'c': true }` => `a c`
2. Array Syntax - `['a', false ? 'b' : '', 'c']` => `a c`
3. Mixed Syntax - `['a', { 'b': false, 'c': true }]` => `a c`
4. String Syntax - `true ? 'a c' : 'b'` => `a c`

And the last can work neatly here as the 2 conditions in the example are mutex:

```
:class="largeCart ? 'section--margin-top' : 'section--full-screen section--centered'"
```

With the following computed:

```
computed: {
    largeCart: (vm) => vm.cartStep === 1 && vm.cart.length >= 3,
}
```

Best pick a name that describes the scenario and not the resulting style.