# Sublime Vue syntax highlighting breaks after :class or :style

Tags: vuejs2, sublimetext3

[image]

In the image above - line 42 (it's highlighted) - notice how before the `:style` line the syntax looks fine, but after Sublime freaks out. *Most notably is the multi-colored closing div tag in line 44.*

The syntax engine seems to think there's an unclosed quote or bracket.

I've noticed this also happens with `:class` - really any attributes where `"{}"` is required.

My guess is this style of syntax is a remnant of vue-1, and unfriendly with vue-2 syntax highlighting, but I'm not sure.

Things I've tried:

- Yes, I could just [make the style value a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804313/vue-class-binding-better-syntax), but this happens a lot in the code base, and I'm not going to build a special function for each instance at this point.
- I've looked through my syntax highlighting options, and there's only one style for `Vue Component`, and that's what I'm using.

<sub>*Keep in mind - this is NOT a one-time thing. It happens on every bracket notated attribute in vue files. If you see an error in my syntax here that you think is causing this, you're not wrong, but that's not the point of the question. I need to know how to fix this obvious oversight.*</sub>

Comment: Is [Vue Syntax Highlight](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vue%20Syntax%20Highlight) the package you're using for syntax highlighting here?

Comment: I think it's [vue-js-complete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vuejs%20Complete%20Package).